# Does the title of a work have to be in the same person as the work?

Tags: grammatical-person, titles, perspective, third-person

In a recent work I wrote, the body of it is, as in most of what I write, in the third person. However, my title is in first person, using the word “we.”

Is this is an acceptable thing to do? Does the title have any bearing on the body in any way?

Comment: It's probably what you meant to say, but "we" is first person plural (not third).

Comment: the original post said the title was in the third person, but it's been corrected in the edit (see edit history - click where it says "edited [time] ago"). Plurality wasn't the point at all.

Answer (score 4):

No.  There are no such requirements for consistency there.

For instance [We the Living](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002PA0LWA) and [All the Light We Cannot See](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DPM7TIG) are in the third person.

Comment: True. Or, going the other way (first person narrator, third person title), "Gulliver's Travels".